# GPU Whistling when Testing Direct3D demo

Tags: drivers, gpu

The other day I decided that I wanted to learn a little DirectX/Dirext3D programming. I downloaded one of the examples showing directX11, and it compiled and ran fine, however, my GPU whistles while the program is running. If I close out of the app, the whistling immediately stops. Restart the app, the whistling is back again, etc. I figured maybe this was just a dust issue, so I went out to the store today and bought a canister of CO2 and cleaned it out. The whistle still persists after the cleaning.

Stranger yet, the whistling seems to be controlled—I can change the pitch of the whistle by resizing the application window with my mouse. The larger I make the frame, the whistle becomes more faint, the smaller the window the higher pitch the whistle is. I also do NOT have this issue when I program in OpenGL; there is no whistle at all, in fact.

There are two things that I think could be causing this issue.
1. A DirectX/Radeon Driver is acting strangely.
2. It is a fan in the GPU speeding up to compensate for varying usage.

Here is a printout from DxDiag showing my computer specs and other goodies:
http://pastebin.com/CZE0UZiZ ***(See Below for new updated settings after driver update)***

I was just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as to how I could solve this issue—before I start digging around in my bios and scouring the internet for patches.

Thanks everyone.

EDIT:

I updated my drivers; the whistling still persists. It should also be noted that the whistling is practically nonexistent when I maximize the window.

Here is the new printout from DxDiag(Updated my drivers)

http://pastebin.com/u4UjD8KJ

Another Edit:

I noticed in the Direct3D example they were not allowing the rendering thread a chance to sleep, so I added a simple "Sleep(1)" and this solves the whistling. However, I still want to know why this is occurring. Typically putting an endless thread to sleep like this means that the CPU gets a split second to rest, but could this also produce the whistling?

This problem is solved, technically, however it is still persistent given the correct circumstances. I hate to leave this question open like this, but I guess it will just have to be that way until I can find a valid—and proper—solution.

Comment: I had a similar problem, oddly, replacing my CPU power supply fixed it. The whistle was from a bad capacitor, when the power draw on the GPU changed it changed the pitch of the sound. Do you have a spare power supply to try out?

Comment: Yep, same here. Try another power supply. Mine was a little bit underpowered and probably had a bad component.

Comment: I do not have a spare laying around, but I will certainly give this a try next time I get paid.

Comment: You guys just gave me an idea though, I am going to try and unplug my cathodes to see if that gives the power supply more energy. If the whistling goes away that would confirm the issue right? Be right back.

Comment: I don't think cathodes take that much power, so you may not have enough boost. If you can borrow power supply do that, it's not necessarily PSU but it is common to have humming and whistling coming from it and doing so in the weirdest situations. For example I had humming when I move cursor on a white surface, or when I drag windows around... It may also be a bad GPU component, it may be something starts resonating, this is really a trial and error thing, but I would start at power supply.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić tried unplugging everything that wasnt vital to the computer running: cd drive, cathodes, and even two LED fans on the top of the case. Ran the program again, still heard the whistling. I have a 600watt powersupply. To be honest, I really think it is the GPU though, I can almost pin-point it with my ear when I listen inside the case. This could just be the sound bouncing around in the case though, I will admit.

Comment: Try PSU first, but if possible don't buy it. You can just take it to service center for test, they probably charge less than what a new power supply costs. Oh, and those cathodes probably have some sort of inverter in a box somewhere and if the box is unshielded they may wreak havoc inside leaking all kinds of electromagnetic energy, so I would unplug those permanently.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić "they may wreak havoc inside leaking all kinds of electromagnetic energy" Can you provide literature supporting that?

Comment: Those are basically power transformers, and most of those work by creating oscillating magnetic fields through a set of wires. Some of the other coils can pick up and create noise in your components, so you may get speaker buzz and such, that's why your power supply has a metal grounded case. It's a "don't use a hair drier in the bathroom", you are probably fine but something really bad might happen. There are few designs used for notebook back light that are much better at containing all that energy so if you have one of those (more expensive is how you know) it's OK.